# knockout - cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I need to fill my trip table with data from two sources: from server using GET when the page loads (to have user's archive trips) and from observable values (when a user adds a new trip). Can I somehow merge those two scripts so that they apply bindings only once? Right now I get an error: You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Add a trip</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="from">From</label> 
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="from" name="from" placeholder="From" data-bind="value: from">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="to">To</label> 
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="to" name="to" placeholder="To" data-bind="value: to">
    </div>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"  role="button" data-bind="click: add()" >Add</a>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class=panel-heading>Your trips</div>
    <table class=table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>From</th>
                <th>To</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: records">
            <tr>
                <td data-bind="text: from"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: to"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript" src="js/knockout-3.4.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
var AppViewModel = function() {
  this.from = ko.observable();
  this.to = ko.observable();
  this.records = ko.observableArray();

};
var model = new AppViewModel();


model.add = function() {
    model.records.push({ 
    from: model.from(),
    to: model.to()
  });


//sending data to server
   var data = 
            {
                from : this.from(), to : this.to(), date : this.date(),  price : this.price(), freeSeats : this.freeSeats()           
            }
            alert(data);

        $.post("/data", data, function(response)
        {

        })

}

ko.applyBindings(model);

</script>

<script>
    function tripModel() {
        this.records = ko.observableArray([]);

        $.getJSON("/usersTrips", function(data) {

          self.records(data);

        })
    }
    ko.applyBindings(new tripModel());
</script>
```

Comment: Your `click` binding should be a function, not a function invocation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give the relevant elements IDs and then apply the models to only those DOM elements.  For example,

**Html:**

```
<div id="add-trip" class="panel panel-default">

<div id="your-trips" class="panel panel-default">
```

**And the binding:**

```
ko.applyBindings(model, document.getElementById("add-trip"));

ko.applyBindings(new tripModel(), document.getElementById("your-trips"));
```

**JSFiddle Example:**

https://jsfiddle.net/hellobrett/49xaqj46/1/

**JSFiddle example going the other direction:**

https://jsfiddle.net/hellobrett/49xaqj46/2/

**Reference:**

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html

> In case you’re wondering what the parameters to ko.applyBindings do,
>
> - The first parameter says what view model object you want to use with    the declarative bindings it activates
> - Optionally, you can pass a second parameter to define which part of    the document you want to search for data-bind attributes. For example, ko.applyBindings(myViewModel, document.getElementById('someElementId')). This restricts the activation to the element with ID someElementId and its descendants, which is useful if you want to have multiple view models and associate each with a different region of the page.

Comment: I think I don't get it. Will it work if I want to apply models for the same element? I have one table and I want to bind to this one table from 2 sources. How to divide it to those 2 'div' elements then?

Comment: Your code had some issues.  See the jsfiddle example in my answer.  The basic idea is that you can reference both models in the script, but you can only *apply* each modle once to any given DOM element.  https://jsfiddle.net/hellobrett/49xaqj46/1/

Comment: But I would like to add data from inputs to the table. Now it seems to work the other way around, right? How to bind from inputs to the table?

Comment: ok, here's an example going the other way around ;)


https://jsfiddle.net/hellobrett/49xaqj46/2/